# Combining tf data and URDF model

Tags: ros, rviz, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have a human URDF model that I can display in Rviz and I am getting tf data from Kinect v2. I am trying to place human URDF model on the tf data so I will have a chance to see the human URDF model moving instead of lines representing skeleton. Is there way for me to do that? Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236879/combining-tf-data-and-urdf-model/) by [onurtuna](https://answers.ros.org/users/26981/onurtuna/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. You should make sure the URDF tree matches the TF tree
2. The name of each link of the URDF should correspond with a TF frame

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2016-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [onurtuna](https://answers.ros.org/users/26981/onurtuna/) on 2016-06-16**:
Can you give me a detailed explanation such as how can I make sure the things you told me above? I am kinda new in these sort of things. Thank you very much!

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2016-06-17**:
What are the names of the links in your URDF? What are the names of the links in your tf data?